# domdocument loadhtml in php

Tags: php, html-parsing

I am scraping one page to update the prices. Data is in table format. I don't want to scrap the whole table. I need to scrap the some rows only. It will defined by row's value. So i am comparing the row's value. But comparison isn't working. I am putting my code also. Here in code comparison is not working.I tried many times. Any lead will be appreciated.

```
<?php
// new dom object
$dom = new DOMDocument();
//load the html
$html =                                                                         
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://example.com");
//discard white space 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
//the table by its tag name
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 
//get all rows from the table
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr'); 
 foreach ($rows as $row) 
 { 

     // get each column by tag name
     $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 
     $value = $cols->item(0)->nodeValue;
     if($value === "xyz")
     {
        // echo the values 
        echo $cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
        echo $cols->item(2)->nodeValue;
     }
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: have you outputed `$value` to make sure its what you think it is?

Comment: yes i did. I got the same result. But in comparison it's not working

Comment: execute `echo '<pre>=='.$value.'==</pre>';` before if

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion.Now i got why if was not working.  Before if i added this and it's working fine. -  $value = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $value));